# How to check a variable Changes

Tags: php, jquery, variables

I have a variable `$curr_price`. Every time some user updates the variable, I want to show a message to the other users.

Should I use a jQuery script something like this:

```js
$("curr_price").change(function(){
  alert("The Price has been changed.");
});
```

And secondly where in my PHP file should I put the script.
In the top of the document or where I want the message to be displayed.
I actually don't want to use an alert box but echo or print the messages in a specific div.

Comment: Is `$curr_price` a PHP variable or a javascript variable? PHP variables are not available to javascript code and vice versa. When the page has been served the instance of PHP and the WordPress code it loaded end. Every new request loads from a blank slate with new variables and new code, there is no persistent running application. The PHP also runs on the server, not the browser. If you want to update the page with the current price as it changes, you will need to ask the server repeatedly for the current price in new requests

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes this is one of the reasons I think I'm struggling, $curr_price is a PHP variable. It is called previously on the page but I will have to set it as a JavaScript variable in the script. Can I set the variable before the function or should I set it inside the function?

Comment: You can print out a javascript variable declaration via `wp_add_inline_script`, but by the time javascript starts to execute all the PHP has finished and the original PHP variable and the WP code that created it have ended and the slate is wiped clean. If you want to update the value you would need to ask the server again in javascript for the updated value, and the server would then need to load WordPress ad calculate the new value. Your PHP code and your Javascript code are separate applications that run on different machines at different times.

Comment: Thank you @TomJNowell it make complete sense. So if I understand it right inside my JavaScript I should call the value from the database again and a sign it to a new variable and then do the ,.change function to check if the value has changed. Will my above code work? and should I put it in some kind of loop to check it continuously?

Comment: your javascript cannot call the database, your javascript can make a request to your site, and the site calls the database. You can make this request every few seconds/minutes to update the page. The code in your question is of no value for what you want to do, you should ignore it. Remember, PHP/WordPress runs on a server machine in a data centre, it outputs a big string of HTML. Javascript runs on the computer infront of you, long after the server has finished its job. Any idea that the variables in PHP are accessible by javascript or can be interacted with is wrong, that's not how it works

Comment: You can't "watch" a PHP variable from javascript. Running javascript has no concept of PHP, no access to PHP, it doesn't even run on the same computer, or possibly in the same country/continent. If you want more data from the database, you have to make a new request that loads WordPress from a blank slate on the server in the data centre. That's called AJAX. Look up using REST API endpoints in WP, and making HTTP requests in javascript. The code in your question is not usable for these things

Comment: @TomJNowell Thank you so much